# How do I prevent pixelization of images on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

I have a curious case where images on the canvas get pixelated after clearing the canvas and redrawing images a couple of times (usually between 6-10 clearing/redrawing).

Pertinent code as follows:

JS clearing of canvas:

`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);`

JS adding of new image:

```
var blobImage = new Image();
blobImage.src = 'blob.png';
blobImage.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(blobImage, x, y);
}
```

HTML (for completeness):

`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600px" height="800px"></canvas>`

So, currently, there is a maximum of 8 blobs on the screen at any point in time.  When this number changes (downwards to 1), on each change I redraw the canvas with one less blob.

Here's what the blobs initially look like:
[image]

Then, after said (variable) amount of redraws they start to look like:
[image]

There is a slight clipping that occurs too.

I'm not using any external libraries, and standard `html` and `js` only.  I don't even know how to start troubleshooting, so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Might help https://dzone.com/articles/how-you-clear-your-html5

Comment: Please share the whole code. How are related the clearing and the image loading parts? What you shown is clearly antialising artifacts, but these should not happen if you clear correctly your context, so if you have it, you probably are not clearing correctly.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, do you reasonably expect users to share their entire code bases?

Comment: We actually **require** that they share a [MCVE]. Note that it has to be Minimal, i.e only what is needed in order to reproduce the problem, but still Complete enough so that we can reproduce. You don't expect a doctor to tell you what medicine you should take without him examining you nor being able to understand what your disease is? Same here.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, I read the requirements for a question too ;)  What I provided is all that's needed to reproduce the problem... I know it's curious, that's why I posted it here.  Now, if you want to help and can't reproduce the problem using the method I described, by all means let me know so we can try find an answer together!

Comment: Well no I can't repro, you state that you draw it multiple times, but in your question we have only single instance of both the clearing and the loading+drawing of image. We need the workflow, to clearly understand how you do clear and redraw multiple times. If I had to throw something on fire, I would say that you are always reloading your image (async operation) and that you do clear multiple times in a synchronous way, which means that at the end you draw everything without ever clearing in between, but that's full speculation, since we miss an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Just change width to 800px and it works:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800px" height="800px"></canvas>
```

or change hight to 600px

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi @stefo91, this isn't a scaling issue by any means, simply changing the canvas does not affect the image rendering.